# Como hacer una acción específica en un formulario de wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

Tengo una aplicación en PHP que recoge los datos insertados en un formulario, los inserta en la base de datos y luego los muestra por pantalla. En concreto es una recogida de firmas. No consigo establecer la conexión con la base de datos de WordPress ni se donde apuntar con el action del form. El código es

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $surname = $_POST['surname'];
            $position = $_POST['position'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
}
```

Comment: Debes apuntar con el **action** a donde tengas ese fragmento de código, ya que es el que se ocupa de recoger los datos por **POST**.

Comment: Eso lo se, mi problema no es la falta de conocimiento sobre el funcionamiento, sino la forma de implementarlo en **WordPress**

Comment: En `Wordpress` existe una variable global llamada `$wpdb`.

Puedes encontrar información al respecto en [este enlace](https://andres-dev.com/utilizando-la-clase-wpdb-de-wordpress/) o en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) de `$wpdb`.